# Iteration through ajax data is working time to time

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I wrote small calculator on python, using flask framework. I created forms in template, in which I gather specific data with Javascript and using .getJSON, I achieve working ajax. Here's code. (Using jQuery as well)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $('.btn#population').bind('click', function() {//Only one button.
        $( ".faction" ).each(function(x) {//Loops through many forms, which all are class .faction
            var totals =  [];//For late r use. Store gathered data.
            $.getJSON('/_population', {//Parse data to python.
                faction: $(this).attr('id'),
                houses: $(this).find('input[name="houses"]').val(),
                level: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val(),
                space: $(this).find('.space').prop( "checked" ),
                senate: $(this).find('.senate').prop( "checked" )
            },
            function(data) {//Receive data. give it to next functions.
                $.merge(totals, data.result);
                /*$.each(data, function(i, item){
                    item.forEach(function(number){
                        //console.log(number);
                        totals.push(number);
                    });
                }); This is commented, due experiments.*/
            });
            console.log(totals);
            $(this).find('input[name="total"]').each(function(i,val) {//Search for fields in forms, wich will store resoults. (Doesn't used for data gathering in this global function.)
                $(this).val();//Here I'll itter througt totals and change values of inputs.
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});

});
```

Forms are consisted of various inputs, but it's not important. `/_population` route has python script, which returns basic json array, consisting only numbers, usually, 3 or 4, like `[0,0,0,0]` or `[120,140,300]`.

My aim is to put each of item of an returned array and put it in input fields in template. As you can see in code, it loops through many forms, and returned array items will goes to some of them. For now, I'm stuck at point, where console shows me very weird behaviour, sometimes it makes proper arrays, sometimes not.

Here's the example of Firefox console output.

```
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [ 40, 120, 300, 0 ] functions.js:23
Array [ 72, 540, 0, 0 ] functions.js:23
Array [ 30, 210, 100 ] functions.js:23
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [  ] functions.js:23
Array [ 40, 120, 300, 0 ] functions.js:23
Array [ 72, 540, 0, 0 ] functions.js:23
Array [ 30, 210, 100 ] functions.js:23
```

(It's irregular at random manner.)

What would be a problem, why it's so and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you have `console.log(totals);` **after** the AJAX (**asynchronous**) call? Also, what is this doing? `$(this).find('input[name="total"]').each(function(i,val) { $(this).val(); });`? Also, why are you using this selector: `$('.btn#population')`? `id`s should be unique, so all you need is `$('#population')`

Comment: @lan Updated with commentary. I cannot answer you for first question, I don't understand it. I can only say, that I'm willing to check, if received array is proper for use later in loop. As I'm having problem with getting out data from array, because sometimes array is empty. That's problem, I wish to understand. Second question - it is for later use, I forgot to remove it. I left comment for now, so it is not important. third question - for more precise tag finding. In case, if binded object won't be a button... matter of taste, anyway.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is **asynchronous**...that means the callback you provide will be executed **later, whenever the response comes back**. You have `console.log` immediately after the `$.getJSON` call, which means the callback will almost definitely not have executed and populated `totals` by the time you log it. So I'm amazed anything is logged (unless the `$.getJSON` calls are cached by the browser).

Comment: @lan I understand that. While communication is active, I get all data properly. But as I need to do it more than once, I'm willing to do all functions in one loop circle. (Send data->get data->store data for next function in loop->use data in function -> start next loop circle). I asume, I don't know, how to handle pause, while response is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the ajax calls in an array and use $.when to get a callback when everything is done and then iterate over the elements and set the value.

It's hard to test this, but something close to this should work.

```
$(function() {
    $('#population').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var xhr = [];
        $( ".faction" ).each(function(i, el) {
            xhr.push(
                $.getJSON('/_population', {
                    faction : el.id,
                    houses  : $(el).find('input[name="houses"]').val(),
                    level   : $(el).find(':radio:checked').val(),
                    space   : $(el).find('.space').is( ":checked" ),
                    senate  : $(el).find('.senate').is( ":checked" )
                })
            );
        });

        $.when.apply(undefined, xhr).done(function() {
            var arg = [].slice.call(arguments);
            $(this).find('input[name="total"]').val(function(i,val) {
                return arg[i].responseText;
            });                                         
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. yes, this was one method I thought now, but as you mentioned, it would be hard to work with, as I understand asynchronous hard points. so I used second method I thought 'bout, and wrote it down. It does what I need, but thank you for your help too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but as it always happens to me, I thought pretty simple fix to problem. As @lan mentioned, getJSON is asynchronus, I thought, that then I should do all fucntions, while I have response, not after I get it. Here's my modified script. Commentaries included.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $('.btn#population').bind('click', function() {
        $( ".faction" ).each(function(x) {
            //Here will answers be shown.
            var answers = $(this).find('input[name="total"]');
            $.getJSON('/_population', {
                faction: $(this).attr('id'),
                houses: $(this).find('input[name="houses"]').val(),
                level: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val(),
                space: $(this).find('.space').prop( "checked" ),
                senate: $(this).find('.senate').prop( "checked" )
            },
            function(data) {
                //Gathered data is stored directly in response function.
                var totals = [];
                //I guess ,can be done by merge too, but for now, I'll leave it like that.
                $.each(data, function(i, item){
                    item.forEach(function(number){
                        totals.push(number);
                    });
                });
                //Here previously gathered answer input fields are used for purpose.
                answers.each(function(y,val) {
                    $(this).val(totals[y]);
                });
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});

});
```